# PHP - Google Api get video files just blank

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive-api

I've already following tutorial and quickstarts google api php, but I just show blank when I run php.

here my php code :

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
define('ID_VIDEO', '0B9LPSEw89uQNSm1GMzQ5MHliMWM');
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE);
$client->setAuthConfig('secrett.json');
putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=secrett.json');
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
$file = $service->files->get(ID_VIDEO);
echo $access_toke = json_decode($client->getAccessToken(), TRUE);
echo $file['embedLink'];
```

above code shows nothing, but icon navicon on tab show video play google icon.
I want to embed embedlink to my `<embed>` but it's just blank too.

Am I missing something to run my php file?

Comment: Are there any logs that can help with checking out the issue? The Service call looks good, though when I tested it out on the API Explorer

Comment: yeah dunno hehe, how to enable debug on google api ?